# How to solve questions involving incoming stream of numbers or characters

Tags: algorithm

I came across a lot of interview questions where input is in the form of incoming stream of numbers or characters. For example:
1. Find the median of an incoming stream of numbers. 
2. Select a random number from incoming stream.

SO what is the point in saying that it is an incoming stream instead of saying that you have those numbers to start with ?

Comment: my guess would be that you probably have to incorperate a mechanism to detect the end of numbers coming opposed to having a fixed number, as the calculation would be easier then.

In the end the logic remains more or less the same, but they probably just want to see if you understand the problem behind the basic math.

Comment: It is useful to know those algorithms because it is helpful with a lot of data. How would you determine the median of 2PB of numbers? You can't read them all into memory and you don't really know how many of them are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can mean several things:

1. The number of elements is too big to keep them all in the main memory. And you don't know how many of them there are.
2. Each element can be processed only once. When we are given an array of numbers, we can traverse it several times. It is not the case for a stream.

The combination of 1. and 2. can make problems much harder. Sometimes it makes it impossible to get a precise answer. For instance, finding a median in of an array is pretty straightforward. However, finding an exact median in a stream of arbitrary numbers is not possible in a general case(if we cannot keep them all in the main memory, of course). However, it is still possible to estimate it. One more example: choosing a random number from a stream so that the probability to pick each element is the same(there is a precise solution here, put it is not obvious). And again, it is easy for an array.

To sum up, a stream usually means that you can see each element only once and you cannot store them all in the main memory, which makes many problems much harder.

Comment: Thank you for forcing me to solve the pick a number at random problem.